# Find out the Employees who were absent for 3 consecutive days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "Attendance"

I want to find out the Employees who were absent for 3 consecutive days.Here in the table the absence date is mentioned for all employees.

The database I am using is Oracle 10G.

[image]

Comment: It's good to want. What have you tried?

Comment: You might want to write an image description at least or better, describe the table "Attendance" in words. While you're at it, perhaps you'd like to tell us what you've tried so far. That really helps people who look at your question.

Comment: Ok... progress for sure... We now know the RDBMS... What ORACLE SQL query have you tried so far.

Comment: So what you need is a query that finds for each employment day what the next day is (or uses sysdate - 1 presumably if there is no subsequent day) and works out whether that next day is more than two days later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLOYEENAME
FROM Attendance AS A
JOIN Attendance AS B ON B.LEAVE_DATE = A.LEAVE_DATE + 1 AND B.EMPLOYEENAME = A.EMPLOYEENAME
JOIN Attendance AS C ON C.LEAVE_DATE = B.LEAVE_DATE + 1 AND C.EMPLOYEENAME = B.EMPLOYEENAME
```

The inner joins will remove all employee who were not absent three consecutive days.

Comment: Dear Micah,What can I use instead of dateadd.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the oracle tag... the edited answer should work (to add a day in Oracle you can just use "+ 1").

Comment: @MicahHahn I added the oracle tag after we beat it out of him :).

Comment: Whoops, I realized that the same id could appear multiple times without the distinct clause.

Comment: well Micah,I tried the same but it throws error.I thought its due to the wrong column name, which I corrected but it doesn't work.

Comment: I expected the column names to be wrong as you only gave us half of the first one :0

Comment: Did it throw an error? Or were no records returned?

Comment: @Micah, it shows ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Oracle's not my strong suit... anyone else know what looks wrong with this query?

Comment: Hey Micah, I got your logic.The problem was due to the ANSI style syntax, it worked with the Oracle syntax. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure, feel free to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of the question, which asks for employees where *were* absent for three consecutive days? This gets employees for which there were three consecutive working days at some time.

Comment: Depends on your interpretation of the column "LEAVE_DATE"... I took it to mean days the employee was not present, in which case the query is correct.

Comment: Thanks Used dateadd to work with SQL SERVER