# Trouble with SQL query - Search for crew members who never flew the same route two days in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope the title is not too confusing. I am learning sql by working on a database for an airline company. For the query I will explain, the following tables get involved:

```
 1. Airplane

plane_number| type | capacity
-------------------------------
I-XX0       | boeing| 200
I-XX1       | airbus| 250

 2. Route

route_id | airport1 | airport2
-------------------------------
1        | LAX      | CDG
2        | FCO      | LAX

 3. Flight

flight_id |      departure        |       arrival      |     plane_number    | route_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AC 000    |  2020-02-11T13:10:00  |2020-02-11T15:15:00 |        I-XX0        |    1
AC 001    |  2020-02-12T13:10:00  |2020-02-12T15:15:00 |        I-XX1        |    2

 4. employee

employee_id |   name    | surname
-------------------------------
     1      |   bob     | black
     2      |   paul    | white

 5. service

employee_id | flight_id 
-----------------------
     1      |   AC 000 
     2      |   AC 001
```

Having this data, is it possible to find out the employees which never worked on the same route two days in a row?

I have tried doing a self join, but I'm not sure that's the right approach.

I hope I've been clear enough, if not please comment in order to suggest an edit.
Thank you all very much in advance.

**EDIT**
In order to make the whole model more clear, here is the ER model:
[image]

Comment: The edit to make things clearer is the part that confuses me. You're on the right track that you'll need a self join.

Comment: @Oso hopefully things are more clear now. I am sorry if my question is confusing, I am very thankful for your attention.

Comment: Are you sure that in your sample data the values of the column `plane_number` in table `Flight` are correct?

Comment: @forpas You are right. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mauretto you should edit the question to add in the query you've tried, or you run the risk of votes to close. People tend to VTC for questions without the attempt.

Comment: I have never really written a query like this one, so what I tried was quite nonsense really. I tried inspiring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217138/13551483) because I found it similar but i cannot imagine how to adapt such a solution to my db. I know this question is very likely to be closed, I tried asking the question in the most detailed way possible hoping someone will help me. Thank you very much for your suggestion, but as said I would not know what to add.

Comment: @Mauretto my one question is you have only `31` reputation so how you will get `50 reputation` on bounty??

Comment: @KUMAR reputation is taken when the bounty is added.

Comment: @Mauretto and if the answer given by OP is not our need then it reputation will return??

Comment: I don't think you get it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't terrible once you break it down into its parts: A query giving `employee_id`s for employees who have worked the same route on consecutive days, and a query of the `employee` table getting all employees whose `employee_id`s don't appear in the first query.

For the first query, we need so find consecutive flights on the same route. The first step is joining `Flight` to itself on the `route_id` and the departure date. The join condition for the departure date should check that the second flight departed one day after the first flight's:

```sql
FROM Flight f1
JOIN Flight f2 ON f1.route_id = f2.route_id
AND CAST(f1.Departure AS DATE) = CAST(DATE_ADD(f2.Departure, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS DATE)
```

Then join each `Flight` to `service` on `flight_id`, and confirm the `employee_id`s are the same:

```sql
JOIN service s1 ON f1.flight_id = s1.flight_id
JOIN service s2 ON f2.flight_id = s2.flight_id
WHERE
    s1.employee_id = s2.employee_id
```

Putting it together, we want to select distinct `employee_id`s, and wrap it in a CTE to join to:

```sql
WITH B2BRouteEmployees
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT s1.employee_id
    FROM Flight f1
    JOIN Flight f2 ON f1.route_id = f2.route_id 
    AND CAST(f1.Departure AS DATE) = CAST(DATE_ADD(f2.Departure, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS DATE)
    JOIN service s1 ON f1.flight_id = s1.flight_id
    JOIN service s2 ON f2.flight_id = s2.flight_id
    WHERE
        s1.employee_id = s2.employee_id
)
```

Now we can do a LEFT JOIN between the `employee` table and our `B2BRouteEmployees` table, and take the employees where the join is NULL -- they do not appear in the list.

```sql
SELECT e.employee_id
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN B2BRouteEmployees b ON e.employee_id = b.employee_id
WHERE
    b.employee_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'd like to test it, but I get the following error: ```Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION airline.DATEADD does not exist 0.000 sec```. Do you have any idea about why this accours?

Comment: What SQL implementation are you using? Though I could swear DATEADD is in the standard. Edit: It's not.

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: Okay, according to the docs the equivalent in MySQL is `DATE_ADD(f2.DepartureDate, INTERVAL -1 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

I cant say this is the best way of doing that - im just scratching the up in a text editor - but I think it should give you an idea of one way of doing it. I think something like this would work;

```
-- Make a temp table / cte / or you could do this as a sub query. you want to show the next departure for each employee route combination 

    WITH flightEmployee AS (
        SELECT  s.employee_id,
                f1.route_id,
                f1.departure,
                lead(f1.departure,1) OVER (PARTITION BY s.employee_id, f1.route_id ORDER BY f1.departure) AS nextDeparture
        FROM #flight f1
        INNER JOIN #service s 
         ON f1.flight_id = s.flight_id
    )
    
    
-- you can then use this to show if it is going to be departing within 24 hours in many different ways - here is one example. 

        SELECT * 
        FROM ( 
                SELECT  employee_id, 
                        route_id,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(hour,nextDeparture,departure) >= -24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As No_Of_Same_Employee_and_Route_Within_24_Hours
                FROM flightEmployee
                GROUP BY employee_id,route_id 
                ) x
        WHERE x.No_Of_Same_Employee_and_Route_Within_24_Hours= 0
```

I count each instance of employee / route combinations within 24 hours - then sum them and select only those employee / routes with a count of zero.

As i said there will be many versions of solving this - maybe some with less code or more efficient - this is simply food for thought.

Comment: I've assumed sql server

Answer (score 0):

SELECT e. name, e. surname
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN  service s ON  s. employee_id = e.employee_id
LEFT JOIN  (
SELECT DISTINCT (f.departure, f. route_id) , f.flight_id
FROM flight f) g ON g. flight_id = s. flight_id

can u try this.